# C# winforms event in Main method for any new form shown

Tags: c#, winforms, program-entry-point

I have two windows forms apps projects (one test and one prod) and a dll project in the same solution.  The two winforms app projects have only one class/function, Program.Main(), the icons I'm asking about, and the app.config files.  They both reference the same dll that contains everything else (including the forms).
What I want is to be able to set the icon (Form.Icon) and text (Form.Text) each time a new form in the app is shown.  The purpose of this is to have different window titles and icons for test and prod (as well as different publish location settings).  How can I accomplish this?  I've tried setting the icon with the Properties>Application>Resources>Icon and Manifest, but it doesn't work.  I would be happy with just getting a different icon, but the text would be a big plus.  Is there an event to subscribe to in the Program.Main() method, before the Application.Run(new Form()), that I can set the Icon and Text Properties as the form is shown, or any other solutions?
Edit: I was hoping for somthing like this because there are lots of forms:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        SomeClass.NewWinFormShown += NewWinFormShown;
        Application.Run(new FrmTrackingList());
    }

    private static void NewWinFormShown(object sender, NewWinFormShownEventArgs e)
    {
        e.NewWinFormShown.Icon = ThisAppsIcon;//from resources
        e.NewWinFormShown.Text += " (TEST)";
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to make any changes to the main DLL?  You could just pass in the icon and window text in the constructor and set it from the DLL.  Then just pass in different values based on which program instantiates it.

Comment: I can make changes to the DLL but I was looking for a more generic solution as I have many forms generated by the first form.  I added an example of what I'm hoping for..

Comment: You can do this sort of thing with windows hooks.  It is however no substitute for proper .NET techniques.  Give these forms another base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `BaseForm` for all the forms you use in your Application, It is not that hard

```
public class AppForm : Form
{
    public AppForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        This.Icon = MyAppSettings.AppIcon; <--read here
        this.Text  = "App Text"
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
For Accessing Icon in dll, just create a static class in Dll and use it

```
//In dll project
public static class MyAppSettings
{
     public Icon AppIcon {get;set;}
}

//In Exe project
static void Main()
{
    MyAppSettings.AppIcon = Resources.Icon;  <--set here
    //Rest of starting App Code goes here
}
```

Then make all your form derive from `AppForm`. this should solve your problem.

Comment: The icons are resources in the projects that reference the DLL.  How would the DLL get the icon for two different apps?

Answer (score 0):

Get values from fields in app.config.

Use slowcheetah to have a app.config that is different for different builds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't set the icon and text in each `Program.Main`.  Save the form, and tweak it.  Instead of

```
Application.Run(new Form());
```

do

```
Form myForm = new Form();
myForm.Icon = theFancyIcon; // from resources, or any other way you want to get it
myForm.Text = myTitleBarString;
Application.Run(myForm);
```

Just make the code different in each version, since you already have different Program.Main files, this should be easy.

Comment: I have lots of forms generated by the startup form and want the same for all forms.  I added an example of what I'm hoping for.

Comment: @zSwizz The same idea applies.  If your startup form is generating other forms, when it generates them, it can set the subform's icon and Text based on its own.  Unless there are lots of different code points where you add forms, in which case I'd consider refactoring your code to make it so there's only one point where the main form loads other forms (i.e. a wrapper function).